# Trying to insert defaltValue to a column through impex but getting error unable to insert default value in the place of null

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, impex

Null value in second column (incoming csv file):->
input CSV: 10512,,
           10513,12345,

impex:

```
INSERT_UPDATE Product;code[unique=true];vendors(code)[translator=ca.batch.converter.StiboSetDefaultVendorIfNullTranslator];...
```

code:

Extending de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.translators.AbstractValueTranslator;

```
private final String defaultVendorCode = "000000";

@Override
public Object importValue(String valueExpr, final Item item)
        throws JaloInvalidParameterException {

    if (valueExpr == null || StringUtils.isEmpty(valueExpr)) {

        LOG.debug("Current attribute value is null so inserting "
                + defaultVendorCode);
        valueExpr = defaultVendorCode;

    }

    return valueExpr;
}
```

getting the same below error here also for the 12345 but final impex conveterd row has the number (impex row -> 10153;12345)

due to Argument mismatch trying to set value '000000' for attribute de.hybris.platform.jalo.product.Product.vendors (got java.lang.String, expected de.h
ybris.platform.jalo.product.Product).,

(impex row -> 10153;;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error message is quite clear on this:

```
(got java.lang.String, expected de.h ybris.platform.jalo.product.Product).,
```

For the translator you'd have to lookup the actual default vendor object instead of returning the default vendor code.

I think the easiest solution would be if you used a Decorator instead that then returns the code values of your "vendors" attribute.
You can find detailed instructions here:
https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/ImpEx+API#ImpExAPI-WritingOwnCellDecorator

but basically something like this:

```
public class MyDecorator implements CSVCellDecorator
{
   public String decorate( int position, Map<Integer, String> srcLine )
   {
      // here add your custom logic to check and if applies return your default vendor code, otherwise return the given input value
      //String parsedValue=srcLine.get(position);
      //return parsedValue+"modified"; // some decoration stuff
   }
}
```

Hope that helps a bit :)

Comment: thanks Mr.Sebastian for your inputs. It really helped.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:[allownull=true] attribute modifier; 
Your impex should look like this:

```
INSERT_UPDATE Product;code[unique=true];vendors(code)[allownull=true]
```

Only Import
true / false 
Default: false
If set to true, this modifier explicitly allows null values for the column values. If there is no business code that blocks null values, this modifier even allows null values in mandatory attributes, such as the catalogVersion attribute of the Media type, for example.
Example:
[allownull=true]
Tip
In the Service Layer mode, import may fail if allownull is set. Since hybris Commerce Suite version 5.1.1, import will switch dynamically to the legacy mode if it encounters this parameter. After processing a given line, the import will switch back to the SL mode.